# Partition of sets

Tags: combinatorics

Each domino piece is marked by two numbers. The pieces are symmetrical so the number pairs are not ordered. How many different pieces can be made using $ \{1,2,\dots,n\} $.

Comment: "The pieces are symmetrical so the number pairs are not ordered". What does this mean?

Comment: Probably $\{1,2\}$ is the same as $\{2,1\}$. The question is from Feller's Introduction to Probability. @AdamRubinson

Comment: Try it for small numbers n. What sequence do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously there are $n$ pieces marked by two equal numbers. For other pieces you can begin with choosing first number from all $n$ numbers, and then choose second one from remaining $n-1$ numbers. It gives $n(n-1)$ pairs, but each one of them is counted twice (assuming that $(i,j)$ is the same as $(j,i)$). So finally there are $$n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ distinct pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Actual domino sets that I've seen have tiles with blanks (including blank-blank). So on these sets the number of ways of choosing a tile with two distinct halves is $${(n+1) \choose 2} = {(n+1)n \over 2}$$ with another $$(n+1)$$ symmetrical pieces for a total of $${(n+1)(n+2) \over 2}$$
So for example a normal set with 1 to 6 spots (or blanks) has 28 pieces. If blanks are not allowed then @Adam is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute : All the different ways , to choose 2 out of n different objects. You can choose with repetition ( more than once , the n objects are available in many copies).
Visualize n holes/baskets and 2 -identical balls. In how many ways can you put the balls in the two 2 baskets? You can do it in $C(n+ 2-1,2) = C(n+1,2)=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$ ways

> Similarly, you will often find in books this identical problem: How many different pairs of two dice are there? A dice can have a value [1,6] ( 6 different choices).
> You have two find every different pair of such. Imagine two empty - white dice and 6 holes ( each one represents a number from 1 to 6). You want to find every possible way to throw the dices there. There is a chance that both of them end up in the same hole. $C(6 + 2 -1 , 2)=C(7,2)=21$